# Наречие и антонимы к ним

Tags: наречие

Помогити, пожалуйста, подобрать наречия, к которым нельзя подобрать антоним?

Comment: Mari, Вас мама не научила говорить "пожалуйста", когда просите, а учительница русского языка — ставить запятые? Пришлось полностью переписывать Ваш вопрос!  
Позорище!

Answer (score 2):

Да ко многим. Например, к вопросительным наречиям нельзя подобрать: где, куда, когда;

к неопределённым: где-либо, когда-нибудь,откуда-нибудь

к наречиям меры : дважды, впятеро, втрое, надвое,натрое, пополам;

по-медвежьи, по-турецки, по-варшавски(кофе), (шашлык)по-кавказски

(сапоги) гармошкой, позавчера, вдобавок

к наречиям на - ски: исторически, по-французски, по-японски